# What is the point of a 16-bit wide character?

Tags: unicode, utf, c11

I am reading the book "C in a Nutshell". It compares the two ways to represent non-Latin characters: Wide characters vs Multibyte characters. It says wide characters use *the same bit width* for every character in a character set (emphasis mine). Then, it introduces the type `wchar_t` and, after the C11 standard, types `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

My question is, in the world of unicode, how useful can `char16_t` be? A character encoded by UTF-16 can be anywhere from 2 bytes to 4 bytes, so a `char16_t` cannot reliably represent it, if one follows the rule that, in wide characters, a character always takes *the same bit width*.

I understand that not everything in a standard may be "useful", and the C standard does not dictate the encoding, so maybe `char16_t` is just there for someone to use. But, **am I correct that, in terms of dealing with Unicode, `char16_t` is not that useful?**

Comment: Well, it's a bit easier than using uint8_t for UTF16... but yes, char16_t is not useful if you want to store full codepoints. ... (Then again, the ability to store full codepoints isn't useful enough either, for properly handling Unicode. (Normalization...) ... you have much more problems than this)

Comment: These are just basic types to help store the coding elements of a codepoint.  `char16_t` is useful for utf-16, you need 1 or 2 of them.  As useful as `unsigned char` to store the coding elements for utf-8, you need between 1 and 4 of those.  Beware that reasoning about coding size is dangerous, a single typographic grapheme can require multiple codepoints.  Google "zalgo" for an excessive example of that.

Comment: the problem is that you're not guaranteed to have `stdint.h` so you need a built in type that is guaranteed to be usable for UTF-16.

Comment: As nowadays Unicode is _the_ standard, with as binary represenation mostly UTF-8, `string` is a more useful abstraction leel than `char`. `ĉ` can either be one Unicode code point or two (`c` plus zero-width `^`) - text normalization required. I would go for a Unicode internal `String` as in java, where there is a `getBytes` with the charset, and a constructor with bytes and charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-16 is a pretty bad encoding, but we didn't know that when Unicode was first envisaged. Back then, 16 bits was enough to store any assigned code point, and UTF-8 with its many desirable properties had not been invented.

Consequently systems that were being built from that time with Unicode support from the ground up — Windows NT and Java, for example — based their string storage types on UTF-16. Those systems, and others that interoperate with them, demand that you use strings with 16-bit code unit semantics to access their APIs.

When you need to talk to one of those systems, a fixed `char16_t` that definitely represents 16-bit code units, and not full code points, is indeed useful.

> a char16_t cannot reliably represent it, if one follows the rule that, in wide characters, a character always takes the same bit width.

That's not a real rule. `char16_t` (and equally `wchar_t` on platforms where they are the same type) certainly can be (and usually is) used to store UTF-16 code units, with astral plane characters represented by two (surrogate) code units.